# Javascript for-loop closure issue in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, scope, closures

I am trying to create a node application that dynamically generates a sitemap based on the existence of certain URL's by using a URL key in a JSON file. However I am having issues looping correctly due to JavaScript closures and can only seem to re-print the last value of the array over and over again.

I have been researching closures within for-loops online but can't seem to find any examples that are relevant to my application which needs to submit a request within the loop.

```
var request = require("request");


request({
json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        var key = [i];

        console.log("before the request, i is " + key)

        request('www.example.com/product/' + key, function (err, response) {
            console.log ("I've checked " + key);
            //if the product page does exist
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                    //print the product URL
                    console.log ("I'm printing " + key);
                    }
            //if the product doesn't exist it does nothing
            else
                {   
                }
    })}

});
```

What it is currently printing is:

> before the request, i is 0
>   before the request, i is 1
>   before the request, i is 2
>   before the request, i is 3
>   before the request, i is 4
>   I've checked 4
>   I'm printing 4
>   I've checked 4
>   I'm printing 4
>   I've checked 4
>   I'm printing 4
>   I've checked 4
>   I'm printing 4
>   I've checked 4
>   I'm printing 4

What i want it to print is:

> before the request, i is 0
>   I've checked 0
>   I'm printing 0
>   before the request, i is 1
>   I've checked 1
>   I'm printing 1
>   before the request, i is 2
>   I've checked 2
>   I'm printing 2
>   before the request, i is 3
>   I've checked 3
>   I'm printing 3
>   before the request, i is 4
>   I've checked 4
>   I'm printing 4

If anyone could let me know how I use a new scope in order for this loop to work correctly I'd appreciate it, I've been scratching my head at this for some time now.

Comment: request is async function., you need use something like https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Node is built for non blocking so all request are async. The loop will keep going regardless of if they request is done or not.